# Component not mounted when setState called in arrow function in React with ES2016

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

***Note:*** I have restructured my question to make it more understandable. However, I have kept the older version for historical purposes.

I have a React application and when I call `this.setState()` from an arrow function, I get the "component not mounted message". Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        value: ''
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <input value={ this.state.value } onChange={ this.onChange } />
    }
}
```

When I type into the input, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

I am not sure why this is, because the arrow function should not have to be binned, and since this is triggered by typing, the component is obviously mounted.

Thanks for any help!

---

*Here is the previous version of this question:*

> I have a pretty standard React application and when I call `this.setState()` from an
>   arrow function, I get the "component not mounted message".
>
> The code looks something like this:
>
> ```
> onClick = () => {
>     this.setState({clicked: true})
> }
>
> ...
>
> render() {
>     return <AnotherComponent onClick={ this.onClick } />
> }
> ```
>
> When `onClick` is called, I get this message:
>
> ```
> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
> ```
>
> I'm not sure what is causing this, because I am using an arrow
>   function but it is still not working.
>
> *EDIT: As asked, here is `AnotherComponent`:*
>
> ```
> const AnotherComponent = (props) => {
>     return (
>       <div>
>           <Button primary>Reject</Button>
>           <Button primary onClick={ props.onClick }>Edit Post</Button>
>           <Button primary>Approve</Button>
>       </div>
>     )
> }
> ```
>
> Thanks

Comment: Is there anything else in the code ? Are you using props ? Have you bounded the method ? Is the component correctly export and imported into the file ? I think it would be clear enough if you could share more code here.

Comment: Show us where the `AnotherComponent` calls `onClick`. Apparently it's not mounted when you do so.

Comment: @Bergi I have added the other component and how it is being used.

Comment: @Ozan I have added the other component, and a little bit more context so that it might be easier to understand.

Comment: @JasonSilberman is it defined it in the same file or are you importing it from another file ?

Comment: @Ozan It is being imported from another file.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `onClick={ this.onClick }` you are saying "here is a function to use". However, it loses its context.

You need to `bind()` the context of `onClick()` before you pass it into your attribute. The best place to do this is in the `constructor` of your class.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props); // have to do this part in any Component constructor
       this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
     }

     onClick() {
       this.setState({ clicked: true });
     }

     render() {
       return <AnotherComponent onClick={ onClick } />;
     }
}
```

Alternatively, if your function is short, you can just create it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.onClick = () => { this.setState({ clicked: true }); };
}
```

By being creating in the context of the constructor, it'll implicitly be bound.

Comment: The OP apparently already uses an arrow function, with the experimental property initialiser syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I noticed that, but I'm still wondering if they aren't binding it in some way. Hard to tell with the small fragment of code they gave.

Comment: I have updated my question with a more concrete example, so that the problem can be better seen.

Comment: @JasonSilberman My assumptions were correct, looking at your updated question. What I gave you should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is perfectly correct, now we only have to know where are you calling it from.

This issue usually comes from the parent, just check if the parent is fully mounted.

Matter of fact:

- `onChange` doesn't need the `e.preventDefault()`,
- as each time you type on the input, it invokes setting the `state`,
- every time the`state` gets set,
- It triggers the lifecycle method `render()` again ( it reloads the node), so in this case.
- when you `preventDefault()`, you're breaking the regular flow of lifecyle components :) 
  remove it and the warning will go away.

====================PART 2 ===========================

Oh I see now, everything is clear :D

```
Whenever you call the onClick = () => {
    this.setState({clicked: true})
}

...

render() {
    return <AnotherComponent onClick={ this.onClick } />
}
```

You're wanting to pass down the function through `props` 
but you're setting it to the `onClick` event, and it's a reserved word

You should pass it through a reserved prop like:

```
return <AnotherComponent handleClick={ this.onClick } />
```

and then on the child:

```
<Button primary onClick={ props.handleClick }>Edit Post</Button>
```

now you created a an actual property

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: So I tried removing the `e.preventDefault()` but I am still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: could you please show me where you're calling this :) ?